# Long or short encryptions?

Tags: algorithm-design

Is it generally considered desirable - or not? - to use an algorithm which encrypts a single byte into a byte array of length around 5 or 10?  Greater length allows me to add additional layers of obfuscation, but I don't know whether this is considered the sign of a naive amateur (which I am).

Comment: Not a clear question? What is your aim? What do you want to learn?

Comment: I just want to see whether I can devise a clever encryption scheme.  I know that everyone says it's pointless; but I find it fascinating to think about.  Thus, I admit to being a naive amateur.

Answer (score 3):

There is no security improvement for using an algorithm with ciphertext expansion. In fact, it's really only an unavoidable side-effect of certain public key operations. It's not something that's desired.

Anyway, time for the obligatory **don't roll your own**. No matter how secure you think it is, it isn't. If you want to learn about cipher design, read about existing ciphers, [like this one](https://www.schneier.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/paper-twofish-paper.pdf).

Comment: Thanks.  I believe you, but I'm afraid I'm incorrigible.  As I mentioned above, I know I should forget about it; but it's actually the only aspect of cryptography that I find truly fascinating.  I think of what I'm doing not as an exploration into a scientific realm, with protocols, proofs, refutations, time and complexity evaluation, etc., but just as a kind of spy-vs.-spy gambit (remember MAD magazine?)

Comment: @RobertRotstein As long as you're aware that any cipher you design isn't going to be secure, it should be fine. But seriously, don't think that, because your design is new or secret, that it won't be trivial to break.

Comment: OP - I also have a similar tendency from time to time.  You just need to remember to not to actually USE your own cryptography.  @forest  Being picky, but OAEP improves the security of the cipher.  I suppose it depends on the cipher/implementation, but a randomised padding scheme should provide additional CPA/CCA security.

Comment: @ModalNest I highly doubt that OP is trying to make an RSA padding scheme. Ciphertext expansion is not uncommon in asymmetric cryptography, but this question is very likely about a symmetric cipher.

Comment: @forest Yeah fair enough.  But it's an example of "expansion" that adds security to (some) ciphers.  Used alongside a secure stream cipher (eg. ChaCha) it would obscure the keystream in the case of a known plain-text.

Comment: @ModalNest I'm not sure what you mean wrt ChaCha. I don't see how it applies.

Comment: @forest I've expanded my thought into a question [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/87438/using-oaep-hypothetically-to-improve-other-cipher-security)